# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment: SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0xca9adb00, pid=18779, tid=39

Tags: java, java-6, java-5

I am migrating application with 1.5 to 1.6 and two databases are connecting to fetch the data for the application. Both database versions are oracl11 and 12c.

While trying to access the application to Oracle12c, the below error is throwing by JVM.

> ## A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
>
> #
>
> ## SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0xca9adb00, pid=18779, tid=39
>
> #
>
> ## JRE version: 6.0_45-b06
>
> ## Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (20.45-b01 mixed mode solaris-sparc )
>
> ## Problematic frame:
>
> ## C  [libclntsh.so.9.0+0x1adb00]  kpuhhfre+0x30

am not sure what problem is and how to resolve this.

Comment: http://admintomv.blogspot.com.tr/2015/02/oracle-forms-builder-11g-r2-on-oracle.html that may help.

Comment: No .This is related to Oracle form builder and the actual issue here is while fetching the data through web application to database, web application is developed on java 1.6 and database is oracle 12c.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's an old unanswered question that doesn't seem useful to anyone at this point and attracts not-really-answers like the one below.